# Use mouseover event in Highcharts Legend to show hidden div

Tags: jquery, highcharts, mouseover, legend, mousemove

One of my legends is called 'Heat production' and when the user hovers over that legend I need a hidden div to appear with an explanation about what Heat production means. I have six legends that I need to attach hover and mousemove events to.

This is what I have so far:

```
var moveLeft = 20;
var moveDown = 10;

$('???').hover(function(e) {
   $('#pop-up-heat-production').show();
}, function() {
   $('#pop-up-heat-production').hide();
});

$('???').mousemove(function(e) {
   $("#pop-up-heat-production").css('top', e.pageY + moveDown).css('left', e.pageX + moveLeft);
});
```

...where ??? is the name of the Legend, and the #pop-up-heat-production is my hidden div with explanation on what that legend means. I guess a for-loop could be used to iterate over all the legends and attach the hover and mousemove events, but how is this done? I have played around with this next code example but all the legends get the last legend attached to it!:

```
events: {
                load: function () {
                    var chart = this,
                        legend = chart.legend;
                    for (var i = 0, len = legend.allItems.length; i < len; i++) {
                        var item = legend.allItems[i].legendItem;
                        var name = item.text;
                        item.on('mouseover', function (e) {
                            //show custom tooltip here
                            console.log(name);  
                        }).on('mouseout', function (e) {
                            //hide tooltip
                            //console.log("mouseout");
                        });
                    }

                }
            }
```

When the mouseover event triggers all the legends output the name of the last legend to the console!

Btw, here is my hidden div:

```
<div id="pop-up-heat-production">
   <p><strong>Heat production</strong></p>
   <p>Some explanation here...</p>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a delegated event on the the chart container object:
http://jsfiddle.net/8zon8tLp/

```
$('#container').on('mouseenter','.highcharts-legend-item',function(event) {
    var seriesName = $(this).text();
    $(".tooltip[data-series='" + seriesName + "']").css({left:event.clientX, top:event.clientY}).show();
}).on('mouseleave','.highcharts-legend-item',function(event) {
    var seriesName = $(this).text();
    $(".tooltip[data-series='" + seriesName + "']").hide();
});
```

Comment: That's a really good implementation. Thanks for taking the time to do a jsfiddle.

Comment: This is great solution but the positions are horrible, how can I correct them?

Comment: You can change the positions by adjusting the left and top in the css call.